# Using attributes among methods within a class

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have a class with three functions with different attributes:

```
 class Weather:
        def __init__(year,month,day):
            #do something with year, month and day
        def crops(beans,wheat):
            #do something with beans and wheat
        def vegetables(tomato,garlic)
            #do something with tomato, garlic and beans
```

I need to use `beans` inside both `crops` and `vegatables` but beans is an attribute of `crops`. Is this possible or I need to include `beans` inside `__init__` to be able to use it in more than one function?

Comment: "beans is an attribute of crops" : nope, it's an argument (and sus become a local variable of the function).

Comment: You're missing `self` EVERYWHERE. I'd say reread the tutorial again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`beans` is **not** an "attribute" of the `crops()` function. It's a parameter to that function. You can make it an attribute of the `Weather` *object* by doing:

```
def crops(self, beans):
    self.beans = beans
```

You can do this in any method, not just `__init__()`

This will be accessible inside `vegetables()` with:

```
def vegetables(self, tomatoes):
    print self.beans
```

as long as you call `crops()` at least once before `vegetables()`.

Whether you *should* do this in these methods, as opposed to initialising shared data in `__init__()` is a design issue that's impossible to answer for a contrived example.

Also, all the methods you have should probably have `self` as the first parameter. (See every Python tutorial ever.) Unless you aim to call them as `Weather.crops(...)`, i.e. using the class as just a namespace, but that is confusing. Better have them as module-level functions or use `@staticmethod` to make your intent clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in `__init__` you would do somthing like

```
self.beans = beans
```

That means that beans becomes a class variable and is available in all class methods.

[Here's](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) some documentation on classes in python

Comment: What if I include all the attributes of all functions inside the __init__ method? Would that cause any problem?

Comment: @ArditSulce No, it would not! :) It is actually a very common practice for `__init__` methods to define all attributes for a class.

Comment: It depends on how your class and your methods should work. But from an OOP point of view, if the variables are attributes of the class you're modeling then it's appropriate to make them class variables but if they only have to do with a specific function, then it's better to pass it to the function.

Comment: It won't become a "class variable", that'd be an attribute of the class object, not of the instance.